# Loop duplicate link

Tags: javascript, loops

I don't understand why my loop duplicate value ?

I have a lot of links in a div, and I just want to add value from the input in each link.

```
      <div class="input-group col-11 mx-auto mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Année:</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="ex: 2021" id="anneeGraphique">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-4 text-center d-flex flex-column">
            <div>Les ventes:</div>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/ventes/">LES VENTES de l'année N</a>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/ventes/repartition/">REPARTITION de l'année N</a>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/ventes/comparaison/">COMPARAISON Année N-1 et N</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-2 text-center d-flex flex-column">
            <div>Les grammes: (total)</div>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/grammes/">Évolution de l'année N</a>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/grammes/comparaison/">COMPARAISON Année N-1 et N</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-2 text-center d-flex flex-column">
            <div>Les grammes: (juste DEEE)</div>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/grammes/deee/">Évolution de l'année N</a>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/grammes/comparaison/deee/">COMPARAISON Année N-1 et N</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-2 text-center d-flex flex-column">
            <div>Les adhérents:</div>
            <a class=" link btn btn-info disabled mb-2" href="/admin/statistiques/adherents/">Évolution de l'année N</a>
        </div>

<script>
let anneeGraphique = document.getElementById('anneeGraphique');
let liens = document.getElementsByClassName('link');

anneeGraphique.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if(anneeGraphique.value.length == 4 && anneeGraphique.value > 2020 && anneeGraphique.value.match(/^\d{4}$/)){
        let anneeBefore = anneeGraphique.value - 1;

        for(const link of liens){
            link.classList.remove('disabled');
            console.log(link.href += anneeGraphique.value+"/");
        }
   
    }else{
        
        for(const link of liens){
            link.classList.add('disabled');
        }
    }
})
```

For the first link I have localhost:8888/admin/statistiques/grammes/2022/2022/ and I would have localhost:8888/admin/statistiques/grammes/2022/.

Can somebody say me why please ?

Thanks

Comment: Your first link is: `"/admin/statistiques/ventes/"` ... I don't see `/admin/statistiques/grammes/2022/2022/` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, but the loop work 2 times, I have explain